# Pass data from laravel controller to Modal

Tags: php, laravel-5, bootstrap-modal, laravel-blade

I want to edit in Modal, but the data does not come through to opgaveRet.blade.php containing Modal :-( Here is my code:
Can anyone help me to see what I am doing wrong?

// route.php

```
Route::resource('/admin/opgave', 'Admin\OpgaveController');
```

//  OpgaveController.php

```
 public function edit($id)
    {

    $tasks = Tasks::findOrFail($id);

       return view('admin.opgaver.opgaveRet', ['tasks' => $tasks ]);
    // also tried :-(:
    //return view('admin.opgave', compact('tasks'));
    }
```

// opgave.blade.php

```
@foreach ($opgaver as $opgave)
// here is a table, and then comes the Action
    <a href="{{ route('opgave.edit', $opgave->id) }}"
           data-toggle="modal"
           data-target="#RetOpgave"
           class="btn btn-primary btn-xs">Edit</a>
    @endforeach
```

// in bottom of opgave.blade.php
  // @include('admin.opgaver.opgaveRet')

```
<div class="modal fade" id="RetOpgave" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="RetOpgave">
        <div class="modal-dialog" role="document">
          <div class="modal-content">
            <div class="modal-header">
              <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close"><span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span></button>
              <h4 class="modal-title" id="RetOpgave">Ret opgave</h4>
            </div>
            <div class="modal-body" >

              @if(!empty($tasks))

    // Here i want to build a FORM::
    // But there is nothing in $tasks  ???????


              {{ dd($tasks) }}
              @endif

            </div>
            <div class="modal-footer">
              <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" data-dismiss="modal">Luk</button>

            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to call the edit function in AJAX.

this one may help you:
https://tutorials.kode-blog.com/laravel-5-ajax-tutorial

Comment: Thanks for the link, it looks like something that I can use,. Thanks!